# How do I prevent clicks on a subform causing updates on the main form

Tags: ms-access

I have a form in a booking system which contains a subform which is a replica of the old ActiveX calendar control that Access 2010 doesn't have anymore. One particular use is to create a new booking.  This means the form is "sitting" on a new record.  However I don't want that record written until I am sure that all the data is properly validated.

However I have a little Gotcha.  If the user clicks on the calendar to select a new date, my master forms Before_Update event fires - indicating that Access is trying to save the forms contents.  As I said I don't want that to happen before I am ready.  So I have added an unbound invisible checkbox to my form which is initialised to false. In the Before update event I check whether it is true or not and if it isn't I CANCEL the update.

The problem is, this seems to prevent the Calendar subform from receiving some of its events.  The days are represented by labels, and they fire.  The bigger events like previous and next month are small buttons.  They don't fire at all.

I know that the Calendar works as it is used elsewhere in the application as a subform and in that place the events fire just fine.

So my question is.  Is there a way to get this form/subform combination working so that I don't end up creating a new record before I am ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This goes against the way access works by default.  the only option I am aware of is to manually load and save your records, ie change all your textboxes etc to unbound in the oncurrent event manually populate the data in the textboxes. when you want to save copy the data from the textboxes back into invisible bound textboxes and mannualy save the record

Answer (score 0):

You can't, as soon as the subform gets focus, the main form will update. I have found in the past that it can be convenient to use a pop-up form for new records. The data can then be added to both forms.

Comment: Unfortunately this is an existing application and I can't radically change the user interface without some complicated discussions

Comment: @akc42 You cannot have an unbound continuous subform and forms that rely on unbound data are going to be an enormous amount of work as all the data has to be extracted from the recordset and written to the form by code. Unbound forms look like a pretty radical change to me - just moving to the next record is going to take some doing.

Answer (score 0):

Probably best to use the built in date picker. As noted using a dialog form that pops up a calendar and let user select the date and then have the form return the value back to the calling code from the form (so you can make a "general routine" that works for any date control.

These approaches will get around this save issue. However as noted Access has always saved record automatic when going from main form to sub form. It does this to force PK autonumber key to be generated + saved.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't.  My client has Access 2000 installed and is not updating it.