# Ms access database is updated when the subform on Mainform is updated via vba

Tags: sql, database, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I have very strange problem I am working with MS access 2013 a application called "failure Analysis system" through which user can enter a different data for different system.

I have cread a main form to enter a data lets say "`Tb_Mainform`" and in this Mainform I have also one subform called "`tb_subform`". whenever user change one combox in Mainform the subform is updated using

```
Me.tb_suform.form.recordsoure = query

Me.tb_subform.requery
```

until now everything is gud subform is also updated. when i click on subform to navigate, it updated the table with half unfilled data.

How can i prevent this. I am opening the main form by using

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "tb_Mainform", WindowMode:=acDialog, DataMode:=acFormAdd, OpenArgs:=C_ID
```

**PS**: Main form and subform using the same database table.

Below is the link with the same problem as mine. it is 6 year old post but i think after that something has to be change in Access until now.

[How do I prevent clicks on a subform causing updates on the main form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9353511/how-do-i-prevent-clicks-on-a-subform-causing-updates-on-the-main-form)

Comment: That's a weird setup. First, you might be better off using a split form. Second, the Requery shouldn't be needed.

Comment: @Gustav yes you are right requery doesn't required. I didn't get you what do you mean by "Split form" . I haven't used any split form.

Comment: No you don't, but you might: [Create a split form](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-split-form-E8EB0EFB-2FA6-4315-9D4B-86E79A1FBE1E)

Comment: @Gustav Split form is not a solution for what i need. I don't want to change the complete design. I think there has to be some work around.

Comment: @Gustav . I found something new.. the think is when the subofrm record changes everthing is good until now, as soon as i click on subform the table is updated...

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Comment: @Gustav how can i avoid updating the database??

Comment: I don't think you can. This behaviour is by design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created an unbound form. It contain subforom where I am saving the records manually in vba.

comment by [ChrisPadgham helped me a lot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9353511/how-do-i-prevent-clicks-on-a-subform-causing-updates-on-the-main-form)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19046778)

Comment: @GregViers "unbound" is the key here. MS Access wont update any table, cause form is not associated with any.